# Azure Active Directory: web api call another web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

I have two different Web API applications (`web-api-app1` and `web-api-app2`) integrated with Azure Active Directory authentication.

I am able to call both API applications individually using some console application like this:

```
AuthenticationContext ac = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/[AD Tenent]");

var clientCredentials = new ClientCredential("app id", "app key");
AuthenticationResult ar = ac.AcquireTokenAsync("https://web-api-app1", clientCredentials).Result;

string result = string.Empty;

HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", ar.AccessToken);

HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.GetAsync("https://web-api-app1/odata").Result;

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Now my requirement is that I need to call `web-api-app2` from `web-api-app1` (web API call to web API call). How do I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement [on-behalf-of](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-on-behalf-of) ([docs for v1 endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-on-behalf-of)) flow.

`app1` should request an access token to `app2` using own access token acquired on user authentication.

Manifest of `app1` should include permission to access `app2`.

If apps are in different tenants, the `app2` should be consented by `app1` tenant admin first.

[The official .net example app](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof)